# SQL query for selecting range of IP and name

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to select records that have one of given IP and name of "admin"?

I have this for IPs but feel that is not the best way of grouping range of it. As stated in comments I want to select "name" which could have IP: "x" or "y" or "z"

```
SELECT DISTINCT (name) AS name
FROM  `log` 
WHERE  `ip` =  '08.88.16.98'
OR  `ip` =  '03.12.27.226'
OR  `ip` =  '03.23.113.116'
OR  `ip` =  '06.204.69.183'
OR  `ip` =  '07.31.0.209'
```

Comment: You want to select a range of IP addresses?

Comment: I want to select "name" which could have IP: "x" or "y" or "z"...

Comment: @Ultra . . . Are you ip addresses really stored with a leading `0`?  The format (to me) looks like nothing will match, because `'08.88.16.98' <> '8.88.16.98'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IN` clause instead of the `OR` statements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (name) AS name
FROM  log 
WHERE ip
IN ('08.88.16.98','03.12.27.226','03.23.113.116','06.204.69.183','07.31.0.209')
AND name = 'admin';
```

> The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE
>   clause.

Just as a side note, you can use the `NOT` clause before the `IN` clause if you want to excludes values, like this, for example:

```
NOT IN ('08.88.16.98','03.12.24.254','03.23.113.189');
```

Read here more about it: [IN (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new table for your desired ip address. give it ips. then join two tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (name) AS name
FROM  `log` 
JOIN `ips` ON (log.ip = ips.ip);
```